# Layout is displayed differently on device and emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-screen

My layout is displayed correctly on emulator with screen size 5.0", mdpi(480*800). When I run app on device with screen size 5.0", 196ppi(480*854), layout gets cut off from bottom.

I tried using `<supports-screens>` but it did not make any difference.

**layout.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/create_trip_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/from_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/from_location_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:imeActionLabel="Ok"
            android:inputType="text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/use_current_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="useCurrentLocation"
            android:text="@string/use_current"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/swap_button_contentdescription"
        android:onClick="swapLocations"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/swap" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to_location"
        style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="@string/to_location_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:imeActionLabel="Ok"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/departuretime_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/departure_date_hint"
            android:inputType="datetime" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/departuretime_time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/departure_time_hint"
            android:inputType="datetime" >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pick_match_create_trip"
        style="@style/big_centered_button_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:onClick="pickMatchesButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/pick_your_matches" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="@string/current_location_textlabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_location_text"
        style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/places_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: The problem is you may have a larger screen on the device than on the emulator but you have less physical pixels in each direction and consequently a lower `dpi`. Device-independent pixels (dp) relate directly to dots-per-inch and not specifically to screen size. You will need to create different layouts for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc etc.

Comment: @Squonk Device screen is 196 dpi and AVD screen is mdpi. They are same. Then should not layout look similar on both?

Comment: @Akash : When you start an AVD you have Launch Options and can specify that you want to scale display to real size. You can then set Monitor DPI based on your monitor screen size and XY resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is brilliant coding right in the xml layout, and checking it with all the available screen orientations and sizes in the GRAPHICAL LAYOUT while designing from scratch.

Comment: As I mentioned in question, I ran on emulator with same specification as that of device. Even that shows different view.

Comment: Is that perfect in Graphical View?

Comment: could you pls post the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

it might have to do with the image density, if you are using the same image of 720 dp, it might behave this way, for a 480*800 , the image density should be 320 dp for a phone screen and 480 dp for tweener tablet like the Streak, for further references, check this

320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).

480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).

600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).

720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I had the similar problem, I used a 720 dp, 720*1280 for a 7-inch tablet and my screen was cut off, getting the 600 dp picture solved my issue and it runs fine with the emulator but fails on the real device. I'm not sure if this solution would work for you! but best of luck with that

Answer (score 0):

Please Check if you have chosen the correct theme for that particular layout. I also had the same problem.